# How to scale a bitmap by height or width only

Tags: android

Please mark this question as a duplicate if it has been answered already, but I can't find it.

So I know how to scale a bitmap by height *AND* width but not *EITHER/OR*

```
Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
     unscaledBitmap, wantedWidth, wantedHeight, true
);
```

How can I scale just by height or just by width **such that the aspect ratio won't change**?

Comment: what do you need a scaled `Bitmap` for?

Comment: Well tell me if this is a stupid Idea. I want the background of my music player to slide the album art of the song it's playing from left to right.  All album art is square and all phones are rectangular.  If I don't want to distort the aspect ratio but I want the image big enough to slide then I should resize the image like in my question. It sounds crazy but I think it makes sense.

Comment: use `ImageView` then

Comment: I did. I put an image view inside a relative layout to use it as a back ground.  The foreground is wrapped inside a linear layout nested in the said relative layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the new height of the bitmap to calculate the width to keep the aspect ratio.

For scaling the height:

```
int newWidth = unscaledBitmap.getWidth() * (1 + wantedHeight /unscaledBitmap.getHeight());

Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
     unscaledBitmap, newWidth, wantedHeight, true
);
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify that I want one dimension to scale in proportion to the other.  I guess now that I think about it one argument could be new height and the other could be old width * (1 + new height / old height) if you want to make that your answer I will check mark you.  You can just add it to your current answer and say this is a second interpretation.